# Throwing an error object in forEach loop does not affect the chain

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise

I have a bug... i want to check in the db of firebase if something is already exist, otherwise go to error catch chain.

but I can not find the bug.

```
const ref = admin.database().ref(`/users/${uid}/programs/${program}/`)
    ref.once('value', snap => {
      if (snap.val() !== null) {
        const registered = Object.values(snap.val());
        const kids = Object.keys(registered[0].registered);
        kids.forEach(kid => {
          if (children.includes(kid)) {
            throw new Error('already registered')
          }
        })
      }
    }).then(() => { ... set to db
```

no matter what it goes to then and to to catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't throw errors in asynchronous callbacks like the one you pass to `once`. Only throw them in *promise* callbacks:

```
const ref = admin.database().ref(`/users/${uid}/programs/${program}/`);
ref.once('value').then(snap => {
//               ^^^^^
  if (snap.val() !== null) {
    const registered = Object.values(snap.val());
    const kids = Object.keys(registered[0].registered);
    kids.forEach(kid => {
      if (children.includes(kid)) {
        throw new Error('already registered')
      }
    })
  }
  // ... set to db
}).catch(err => {
  // ...
});
```